# SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed vs Lazily

Tags: android, kotlin-stateflow

There is `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed` and `SharingStarted.Lazily` both are used `Flow.stateIn()` of Android Platform.
I read the explanation in the official documentation, asked chatgpt, and googled it.
But I'm not sure what the difference between the two is.
Does anyone know the details of the difference?

I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed` and `SharingStarted.Lazily` is the lifecycle of a producer.

1. `SharingStarted.Lazily` starts sharing data when the first subscriber appears and after that the flow will be kept active **forever**. So after sharing was started it will never stop.
2. `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed` starts sharing data **only if there are active subscribers**. So it **stops immediately** when the last subscriber disappears.
3. Also there is `SharingStarted.Eagerly` strategy. It just stars immediately and never stops.

Note: that in case of `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed` you can provide `stopTimeoutMillis` to set some timeout, which configures a delay between the disappearance of the last subscriber and the stopping of the sharing coroutine. By default, it is zero, that's why it stops immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You can find here an article explaining the difference in more details:
https://blog.p-y.wtf/whilesubscribed5000

With `SharingStarted.Lazily` if you use it in a ViewModel it will be sharing the data until ViewModel is destroyed